# TextView.setText() not working on sony smartwatch

Tags: android, textview, sony, sony-smartwatch

I am trying to change the text in a textView on the sony smartwatch control extension by a button click. However, `TextView.setText()` method seems not working.

Here is my ControlExtension extended class

```
class SampleControlSmartWatch2 extends ControlExtension {

    private static TextView textView = null;

    SampleControlSmartWatch2(final String hostAppPackageName, final Context context,
                Handler handler) {
    //...

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sample_control_2, null);

        textView = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.textToBeChanged);
    }

    //...

   public void onObjectClick(ControlObjectClickEvent event) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Before : " + textView.getText().toString());  // It shows "original"

        textView.setText("changed");

        Log.i(TAG, "After : " + textView.getText().toString());   // It shows "changed"

        textView.invalidate();           // These two methods are added after read
        textView.requestLayout();        // through several posts but it doesn't work
   }   
}
```

The logged text of textView in LogCat is shown as expected but the text in the emulator does not update. Anyone know how to solve it? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me this code works:

```
sendText(R.id.textToBeChanged, "changed");
```

Comment: Yes, it works. Do you know how to change text that in the host application?

Comment: You mean triggering an update of a control in the app on the smartphone from your SmartWatch app? I solved this by sending an intent to which the app had registered.

Comment: I am trying to trigger a button click on smartwatch app and then change the text in the app on the phone.

Comment: Then you should send an intent in the SmartWatch Extension and add a BroadcastReceiver in the Phone app. If you need help with this, please open a new question because it is too much code to write in the comments

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, let me try for a while first. :)